# How to include DLLs during debugging and redistribution?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, path, environment-variables

This question has been asked and answered several times on SO, but I cannot get the proposed solutions to work for my situation. I am using a library which depends on many  (~50) DLLs. This is Windows 7 x64, Visual Studio 2015, C++.

OBJECTIVES: (1) During development, give the debugger access to the required DLLs.
(2) For deployment, provide the needed DLLs either in a Windows installer or as a compressed file to be copied into the executable's folder, or another folder. If the DLLs are not in the executable's folder, there needs to be a means of telling the pgm during execution.

For (1), I attempted to modify the Configuration Properties / Debugging / Environment variable, to add the path to the DLLs, C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin. This doesn't work for some reason.

Before I changed anything, the Environment variable shown in configuration was`$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)`, the Evaluated value was `PATH=;%PATH%`, and the Inheirited values was `PATH=$(VCRedistPaths)%PATH%`.

After adding my entry, I had

Environment:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin%PATH%$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)
```

My entry:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin%PATH%
```

Evaluated value:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin%PATH%
PATH=;%PATH%
```

Inherited values:

```
PATH=$(VCRedistPaths)%PATH%
```

but starting the debugger does not find the DLLs.

What is the proper way to change the path environment for the VS debugger?

What is the suggested means to deal with part (2), deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the `PATH` environment variable concatenations look problematic.

Try inserting `;` (semicolon) separators wherever there is a logical concatenation of literal strings and variables.

For example:

`PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin%PATH%$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)`

would become:

`PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin;%PATH%;$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)`

and

`PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin%PATH%`

would become:

`PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin;%PATH%`

and so on.

Comment: Now I want to set a new env variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX` and add a new `PATH` variable. As your answer, I fill it out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJOI0.png). But I get a error information showing the `TESSDATA_PREFIX` is failed to set..

Comment: @yode That syntax is (I believe) just adding your `TESSDATA_PREFIX` to your `PATH` string (the `;` isn't doing what you want it to do).  Instead, click the drop-down in that Environment cell and click `Edit...`.  VS will open a dialog box where you can add variables - one per line.  Together they will look like one long string when you return to the Debugging tab.

Comment: @yode My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a semicolon between your path entry and the `%PATH%` environment variable.  Try:

```
PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin;%PATH%
```

Another option is to set your `%PATH%` in the system environment to include the directory containing DLLs.  You'll have to restart Visual Studio to pick up the environment changes.  This option is probably not necessary if you set the path correctly in the debugger.

Your DLLs can be in the same directory as your program and they will be found by the program in most cases.  (There are exceptions...)  You can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) about how Windows searches for DLLs when running different types of programs.

An easy way to see where the program is searching for DLLs is to use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to show you in real time paths where the program is searching for DLLs.

Comment: I changed my entry in the Environment configuration to PATH=C:\ProgramFiles\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin;%PATH%; as suggested, and it makes no difference. BUT, I also unchecked the box at the bottom "Inherit from parent or project defaults", and now there are no more "DLL missing" messages when I start debugging. I have no idea what's going on. Maybe it has something to do with the PATH=;%PATH% that appears in "Evaluated value".

Comment: Try out process monitor.  It will help you troubleshoot the problem.